# How to withdraw Stripe balance to own bank account using API?

Tags: php, api, stripe-payments

I used to have a cron script that runs every week to withdraw cash from my Stripe balance to my bank account. We are now re-visiting Stripe (we left them for a diff payment processor, but we are returning back to them), and I've come to learn that the `Recipients` object is now deprecated.  I've been unable to find a simple way to do this with the new method they are suggesting (via `Connect`).

This was my old code:

```
$stripe_bal = Stripe_Balance::retrieve();
$stripe_avail = $stripe_bal['available'][0]['amount'];

if($stripe_avail > 1) {
    $transfer = Stripe_Transfer::create(array(
        'amount' => $stripe_avail, // amount in cents
        'currency' => 'usd',
        'recipient' => 'self',
        'statement_descriptor' => 'stripe balance cash out'
    ));
}
```

How do I do the same exact code above for their latest API using `Connect`?  I'm unable to find an exact example or documentation that covers or even mentions this.  I know how to do it manually on their GUI, but I'd like to automate it using their API, since it's going to be tedious to have to log in every week to clean my account.  I don't want to clean it out everyday either; I want to stick to doing it once a week.

Comment: `Recipients` are being depreciated but this should not impact Manual Transfers to your own bank account. You can continue using the same code here to pay out your balance on a weekly interval.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are curious, I finally figured this one out.  Here's how to do it using API version `2017-01-27`:

```
$stripe_bal = \Stripe\Balance::retrieve();
$stripe_avail = $stripe_bal['available'][0]['amount'];

if($stripe_avail > 1) {
    $transfer = \Stripe\Transfer::create([
        'amount' => $stripe_avail, // amount in cents
        'currency' => 'usd',
        'destination' => 'default_for_currency',
        'statement_descriptor' => 'stripe balance cash out'
    ]);
}
```